Is epiphenomenalism falsifiable?
In the debate on the nature of consciousness, especially concerning views like epiphenomenalism, can we design experiments to test whether consciousness, regardless of its underlying nature, has causal effects on the physical world, thereby allowing us to falsify epiphenomenalism? In other words, is epiphenomenalism a falsifiable hypothesis?

What motivates the question?

@ScottRowe Curiosity.

Ok. I think there are a large number of ideas that need to be conclusively falsified, so I wish you success.

Not on its own and not any time soon. Not even scientific theories are falsifiable without auxiliary hypotheses that connect their constructs to observable behavior. In the case of epiphenomenalism, we would need a way to track consciousness independently of physical observations to test whether changes in it can go unaccompanied by physical changes. That is a tall order and far beyond our current capabilities, we cannot even correlate mental to physical events very well at this time.

Gosh, I was really wishing we could consign this idea to oblivion. We'll just have to wait for larger supercomputers I guess.

If one were to accept the metaphysical possibility of p-zombies, then it would be hard to avoid a corresponding metaphysical possibility of epiphenomenalism - but, to accept the former, all it takes (according to the standard argument for them) is to find them conceivable.

In a rigorous, academic sense, not until we can perfectly simulate the human brain and detect "extra-material" changes to the brain which could presumably come from the entity (or entities) we call consciousness could we falsify epiphenomenalism scientifically (well enough to publish in a scientific journal, anyway).
However, we can argue that epiphenomenalism as a theory leaves some confounding questions that interactionism does not (and vice versa).  In particular, if epiphenomenalism is true and consciousness has no effect on the physical world, then how is it that our brains seem to perceive consciousness in some way and be aware of it and cause our fingers to type questions about it on StackExchange?
The answer is either that the idea of consciousness (as it exists in our neural networks) has some evolutionary advantage and that it coincidentally evolved in parallel with consciousness itself (as we experience it), or epiphenomenalism is false and consciousness does affect the physical world in some way.
Disproving the first alternative, however, is incredibly difficult (as difficult as disproving the existence of the Flying Spaghetti Monster), but in order to support it you have to explain away the existence of the idea of consciousness evolving in a universe where consciousness has no physical effects, which is also incredibly difficult.  Whether that counts as close enough to falsification is up to you.  Beware though: the alternative to epiphenomenalism is to adopt something like interactionism (by which I mean some theory that posits that consciousness has a causal effect on the physical world), and that's a whole other can of worms.

Welcome! Make sure you take some time to read the Help Center.

We get the theories we deserve, I suppose.

The stark dichotomy presented in your final sentence is not, as far as I am aware, widely accepted.

@A Raybould Either consciousness has an effect on the physical world or it doesn't.  I'm not sure I understand how that dichotomy could be less stark than the way I presented it, but I'm willing to be corrected.

I see that the term 'interactionism' seems to be used rather loosely, but the impression I get is that, within philosophy of mind, it is generally regarded as a dualist position - e.g. in the SEP, where parallelism is presented as a third option. Neither all all physicalists ipso facto epiphenomenalists (and my impression is that few are.) On the other hand, for all I know, interactionism may be commonly used as simply the antonym of epiphenomenalism, I just haven't seen that usage.

I am using interactionism pretty loosely here, yes.  I mean by it "any theory that posits that consciousness has a causal effect on the physical world".  I'll edit my post to clarify what I mean.

From the SEP entry

Epiphenomenalism is the view that mental events are caused by physical events in the brain, but have no effects upon any physical events.

"Consciousness" is the vague catch-all term you are presumably using to refer to any or all mental events and processes. Or perhaps you use it to refer to a particular mental process, like "self-aware deliberation" or "self-awareness". In any case, it's a mental event, or a stream of mental events, and as such it can by definition have no causal impact on any physical events, according to epiphenomalism.
Epiphenomalism may seem "obviously" false from an everyday, self-reflective point of view. Since, if I deliberate about some options, and make a choice, in other words, take action, trying to realize some plan, am I not causing some effects in my body and environment? The difficulty in understanding (a coherent view of) epiphenomalism is that the answer to that question, according to epiphenomalism is both yes and no. It's yes, you are causing changes, but you don't really know what this "you" is or how it works and how it effects changes (in the body). "You" (or your "mind", your "consciousness") are like a shadow that follows the actual, underlying biochemical processes (in your brain and body). The actual causes are those underlying processes.
If epiphenomalism holds that mental processes can as such have no causal impact on anything, does this mean it's not an empirical theory and cannot be empirically tested? No. This is also not (necessarily) true.
Think of how software runs on a computer. Software as such has no causal impact on anything. As such, it's a purely symbolical, abstract process -- a mathematical dynamic process -- an algorithm, for instance. It's only the hardware processes --  that are "controlled" by the software -- that have causal effects. The question is really, what does this "controlled by" mean? How does that work? Doesn't that mean that its the software that has effects? No. Bits don't switch transistors. Bits are pure abstractions. But transistors can be seen as encoding bit states. So, what we have are two different layers of description, which can generate two descriptions (or explanations) of one and the same process. There is the physical process (of current flow, voltage differences, transistor states) and the information processing process (the running algorithm) that follows this as a shadow.
So, now you can still ask: But in biology, how or why does this
"informational processing process" start? I think nobody has a very clear answer to that -- it's a question clouded in a philosophical dust storm. The way I think about it is to consider this analogous to emergent computing where in the emergent process a model of that process itself is also constructed.

I think you're making a category error with your analogy about software, a conceptual abstraction of a physical process. Epiphenomenalism does not specifically describe consciousness as a purely emergent phenomenon or a high-level abstraction. Although those may be reasonable ways to describe consciousness within an epiphenomenal framework, they would then have to build upon something else non-physical. Unless you're really making a "turtles all the way down" argument here, you can't wave away epiphenomenal consciousness as emergent without replacing it with something non-emergent.

Well, there must be "something" non-emergent just like a clean computer needs a bootstrapping process. I'm not denying that - but that something cannot be "in" consciousness. I haven't quite made up my mind otherwise about "turtles all the way down" -- at least there must be quite a few layers of turtles. Sentience seems a more interesting problem and more basic here. Somehow pain seems to be borderline in between being a signal and having meaning. I'm tempted to see pain as the border of consciousness. I don't understand why this doesn't get more attention in these kind of discussions.

In other words, if I'd still be working in this field, I'd want to work on making a sentient robot, rather than on AGI :)

@mudskipper "So, what we have are two different layers of description, which can generate two descriptions (or explanations) of one and the same process." Let the OP note that the ISO's OSI model has 7 layers of abstraction: APSTNDP, and so implicit in your claims is some sort of property dualism: there are only physical processes, but as many abstractions as we feel to make of them. We can settle for body and mind, or we can do what Lakoff does and claim there is body, neurons, and mind.


[C]an we design experiments to test whether consciousness, regardless of its underlying nature, has causal effects on the physical world, thereby allowing us to falsify epiphenomenalism?

Hypothesis 1:

The physical world causes consciousness.

Hypothesis 2:

Consciousness causes no effects in the physical world.

If H1 and H2 are true then scientific experiments can only be designed and conducted by an underlying unconscious physical process. The unconscious physical world would be forming hypotheses, designing experiments, and attempting to invalidate the hypotheses. This is the meat puppet model for philosophy and science.

Yeah. I mean, an unconscious world would be doing some pretty odd things if that was true. Why do them only when consciousness also arises? Why isn't the Sun conducting experiments as it goes across the sky, and rivers forming hypotheses as they flow and so on? Maybe it's a new way to look at Evolution? Experimenting away...

@Scott Rowe Sigmund Freud argues that consciousness is an attribute or feature of the biological ego. He describes the ego as the structure in the psyche that moderates between biological drives and external reality. In my introspective analysis the body performs a biological function: the body makes conscious efforts to govern action in the sensory context. This function, which is both conscious and unconscious, is at the core of everything Freud maps to the ego. The ego function is driven by the effort to gain and keep vitality - the ability to live. I experience human drama as my ego-drama.


According to a current hypothesis from neuroscience: Conscious
mental processes make available new information from distinct
sensory areas to all brain areas to whom it may concern. It is a
kind of brodcasting or information spreading.

The biological goal of all animals including humans is to decide
about an adaptive action as reply to the actual sensory input and
depending on the local state of the individuum. Hence it is
advantageous if locally generated information is made globally
available.

Nevertheless, this hypothesis does not explain why decision making
is experienced as a conscious process - the question for the benefit for the individuum that these processes are consciously experienced, is still open.
I do not know of
experiments in neuroscience which are able to test     epiphenomenalism. I am curious if others know about such ongoing
experiments.



Before we try and test a theory, it's important to have a good conceptual grasp   of what it is saying.
At the root of epiphenomenalism is the concept of epiphenomenon. If I understand it well, it postulates the existence of certain things that are non-causal. They cannot interact with anything else.
Now, a phenomenon (from Greek phainomenon ‘thing appearing to view’, based on phainein ‘to show’) is generally defined in philosophy as "the object of a person's perception." So, a phenomenon is something as perceived, while an epiphenomenon is something that cannot be causal and therefore, that cannot be perceived.
An epiphenomenon is NOT a phenomenon, because their definitions are mutually exclusive. So what is it? It is a non-phenomenon: something not showing at all. An invisible, unheard, untouchable thing.
Evidently, the idea that there exist such thing that are "not showing", cannot be tested. It's a metaphysical postulate. Either you believe it or not. Personally, I don't see a need to postulate their existence. I can easily exclude such ethereal beings from my worldview because they make no difference, literally. By definition, it doesn't matter whether they exist or not.
For the sake of the argument, we could tweak the definition of epiphenomenon to something more realistic, like "stuff that has very weak causal power." Like the neutrino if you wish.
Is the theory that mental events have very weak causal power testable? I guess yes. One could look at the history of mankind, say at the 20th century, and try and describe and explain it without any recourse to ideologies such as marxism, fascism or liberalism. Seems difficult to do convincingly, though.
Another approach would be the Darwinian track: can one explain the existence of mental events in Homo sapiens today without assuming any survival or reproductive advantage of that peculiar trait? Supposedly, we have eyes because vision provided an advantage to our pre-human ancestors. Why do we have thoughts? Can epiphenomenalists explain the very existence of mental events from a Darwinian perspective?

I agree, all of these untestable ideas are the equivalent of the Bogeyman in Philosophy. Halloween is over, you-all come out now!

@ScottRowe Indeed, talks about epiphenomena are magic thinking, as absurd as the tooth fairy. The concept is an oxymoron.

If consciousness has causal efficacy it may be difficult but possible to test.  Somehow certain areas of the brain influenced by consciousness would register differences in the quantum probability function consistently altered from what would be expected otherwise. This violates closure of the known physical laws.  However, if there is no mental efficacy and the mind is purely epiphenomenal I don't see how this could ever be tested.  How do we test invisible entities (other minds) that have no independent effect on measuring devices? Therefore epiphenomenalism is not falsifiable.  see https://philarchive.org/rec/SLEPAR
